# Created Daily Notification in android studio on specific time but Its appearing whenever I run the app

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager

I am putting this code in ***OnCreate*** and had two versions to set time with Calender and Date

I have created the code for notifications using alaramManager and Notification Manager and invoking pendingIntend method to get notifications at a specific time but whenever I run the app I am getting notifications.

```
  Calendar calendar = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        calendar = getInstance();
        calendar.set(HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
        calendar.set(MINUTE,min);
    }else{
        date = new Date();
        date.setHours(hour);
        date.setMinutes(min);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Notification_reciever.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),uniquecode,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
    }else{
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,date.getTime() ,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

My Notification Rececvier is this

class Notification_reciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 =PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 =PendingIntent.getActivity(context,102,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder1.setContentIntent(pendingIntent1);
    builder1.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.plan);
    builder1.setContentTitle("Night Notification");
    builder1.setContentText("Plan Tommorow");
    builder1.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationManager.notify(100,builder1.build());
```

}
}

Comment: What is the issue at hand and intended behaviour? It should be stated clearly in the post. Also do consider improving your code formatting.

Comment: I have created the code for notifications using alaramManager and Notification Manager and invoking pendingIntend method to get notifications at a specific time but whenever I run the app I am getting notifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting that code in `onCreate()`, then it is running every time you open the app.  Everything should work currently as long as you are setting the alarm for some time later in the current day (for example, its 5:00pm and you set it anywhere from 5:00pm to 11:59pm.

However, the problem which is causing your alarm to fire immediately upon opening is likely caused by the alarm being set for a time that has already passed in the current day, which always causes the alarm to fire immediately - for example if it was 5:00pm and you tried to set an alarm for 1:30pm, it would not fire at 1:30pm tomorrow but instead would fire immediately.

To fix this you need to check if the alarm time you want has already passed for the current day, and if it has then add one day onto your calendar object so it fires tomorrow instead of immediately.

The code snippet below checks if the calendar time you have set has already passed, and if it has then it adds one day so it fires correctly tomorrow.

```
 if(calendar.before(System.currentTimeMillis())){
     calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
 }
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
Calendar calendar = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    calendar = getInstance();
    calendar.set(HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    calendar.set(MINUTE,min);

    if(calendar.before(System.currentTimeMillis())){
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

}else{
    date = new Date();
    date.setHours(hour);
    date.setMinutes(min);
}
```

I am not sure why you are using `Date` for anything under Nougat, I have used `Calendar` for `AlarmManager` times for devices as low as 4.x successfully, but if you need it for some reason then you should be able to do the same time check on it and add the equivalent of `calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);`.